# jquery change dynamic button color when its clicked and send it to a listbox

Tags: jquery

I have problems to change background color of dynamic created buttons.I have lots of button on the page created dynamically.I want to have in the first click to the button to change background color to green on the second click i want to take this change back.Wıth below code i tried to do it with %2 ==0 but than i realized it second click could be on other button and even it is the second click i want to make it green.I think i have to loop through every button than apply below code but i couldnt do it(This was my first question).Second question is finally i would like to send just green buttons value (text value) to a listbox.Below is my code but i am not succeed it.Can you please help

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" Width="111px"></asp:ListBox>


        $(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('input[type=button]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                count += 1;
                if (count % 2 === 0) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#6FA478');
                    var value = $(this).value;
                    $("[id$=ListBox2]").append($('<option/>').text(value).attr('value', value));
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: `on()` isn't magic, you still have to assign the events bound with `on()` to an element that exists in the DOM at the point of DOM-ready (usually the parent/containing-element of the buttons).

Comment: @DavidThomas, soooooooo?dont give me history lesson,write codes

Comment: Oh, now *there's* an incentive to bother helping. Anyway, what's the actual (relevent/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML? ('view source' in your browser, the server-side script is entirely irrelevant to JavaScript).

Comment: @DavidThomas, your comment was completely useless,the problem is simple get the green buttons (alot of buttons when you click on the same button twice it turns from green to default) and send it to listbox.Thats it,i get nothing to do with your comments

Comment: @Asil, your question is not clear. Formatting issues aside (walls of text are pretty hard to read), you never explain what you mean by `send just green buttons value to a listbox`. Your general attitude is not helping either. If the problem is so simple, please try and explain it in a more understandable way.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Ok,i will try to explain.I have a lot of dynamic created buttons on the page,I would like to click on it and change the background color to green to see that its selected and send this button value to a listbox.But if the user changes his mind and click on the same button to show that he doesnt want it in the listbox i want to make it background color default.Finaly i want to have in the listbox just green buttons value.

Comment: @Asil, that indeed makes your intent clearer but unfortunately still doesn't clarify what you mean by the `button value`. We do not have enough context to deduce what that is supposed to mean (I can interpret that literally as the button's text, for instance). Can you provide that context (preferably by editing your question, not in comments)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I updated my question,yes button value means text value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this, It will make a button green and store in list if click on first time, if second click then it will remove from list box and remove the green background color also, and it will work continue in on and off mode.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=button]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var toggle = $(this).data('toggle');
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(toggle && toggle == "1") {
            $(this).css('background-color', '');
            $('[id$=ListBox2] option[value="'+value+'"]').remove()
            $(this).data('toggle', '0');
        }else{
            $(this).css('background-color', '#6FA478');      
            $("[id$=ListBox2]").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
            $(this).data('toggle', '1');
        }
    });
});
```

or you can try **[.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)** also like

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=button]').toggle(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var value = $(this).val();
       $(this).css('background-color', '#6FA478');      
       $("[id$=ListBox2]").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
    }, function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var value = $(this).val();
       $(this).css('background-color', '');
       $('[id$=ListBox2] option[value="'+value+'"]').remove()
   });
});
```

Comment: @YoprajGupta, Hi Yopraj, i checked it coloring is working but it doesnt remove from listbox when you click the same button second time i mean when the button color is default.Can you please help.

Comment: @YoprajGupta, i am afraid i chacked again but same result i get.i can not remove the button from the listbox which its color default.

Comment: @AsilEris, Check updated answer, It will solve your issue, there was some mistake in remove now corrected.

Comment: @YoprajGupta,Thank you very very  much,this is what i want

Comment: @YoprajGupta, last question if i want to use this code for button class,because for some of the buttons i want to put their values to another listbox (listbox3).I think i have to change the code from     $('input[type=button]')    to   $('.btnclass')   or??

Comment: @YoprajGupta, Yopraj one point,if i updated the code and i use it with class approach.Now i want to have for the specific class that if i click one button the others should be default color.and listbox logic will be the same of course.How can i achieve this,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':button').toggleClass(["red", "green"])
```

in your css file, ensure that red and green have values